# Find the volume of the solid restricted to $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Find the volume of the solid restricted to $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$

---

I think the volume is given by $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\rho^{2}\sin\left(\varphi\right)d\rho d\theta d \varphi$$

Is that right? What if I wanted to use Cartesian coordinates?
I would say it's something like $$\iint_{D}^{ }\int_{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}+1}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}}dydzdx$$
Though I can't find $D$.

Comment: Starting from 3.04 you ask almost the same questions every day. Do you have so many homework?

Comment: Do you really need to use multivariable calculus?

Comment: @If you don't want to restrict yourself to using multivariable calculus, there is a really easy method to calculate the volume.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the volume as follows

\begin{align}
V &= \iint_{x^2+z^2<\frac34} \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}}dy \> dxdz\\
&=\iint_{x^2+z^2<\frac34} \left(2\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}-1\right)\> dxdz\\
&=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt3/2} \left(2\sqrt{1-r^2}-1\right)\> rdr \\
&= \frac{5\pi}{12}
\end{align}

Comment: Why the lower bound of $y$ is $1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}$ instead of $1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}-z^{2}}$

Comment: @masaheb - the + sign is for the right half of the sphere and the - sign for the left half. You need the left half for to enclose the volume